# Automatize download files with POP UP

Tags: .net, download, obiee

I need to develop a script to automatize the download of OBIEE reports.
When i open the report url, a popup is shown and i need to click on Save.

I would like to bypass this step.

Why ? 
Because i need everyday to download 10 reports and it's time consuming and not user friendly for the final users.

I develop on Visual studio with vb.net but i'm open to have a script in another language.

Of course i spent many times on google to find a solution without success ...

And it's not possible for me to use webservices due to credentials limitations.

Thanks for your help ;-)

Alexis

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Agents, and have the reports emailed directly to you?